# My database query display sorts values into alphabetical order

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been trying to figure this problem out without asking for help, but I have reached the point where I honestly can not figure it out.

Here is the function I use to query the database (I have had to change name for confidentiality):

```
public Cursor getAllItems(){
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String []{KEY_NAME, KEY_1,KEY_2, KEY_3,
                KEY_4, KEY_5, KEY6,
                KEY_7, KEY_8, KEY_9, KEY_10, KEY_11, KEY_12,
                KEY_13}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor;
}
```

This is where I populate a tablelayout that has been created using xml.

```
public void populate(){
    db = new DBAdapter(this);

    TableLayout TL = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);        

    db.open();  
    c = db.getAllItems();       
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(Integer.toString(c.getPosition())!=null){
        TableRow TR = new TableRow(this);

        TR.setId(c.getPosition());

        TextView column1 = new TextView(this);
        TextView column2 = new TextView(this);
        TextView column3 = new TextView(this); 

        TR.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));         

        column1.setGravity(0x01);
        column1.setTextColor(0xff000000);
        column1.setTextSize(2,20);
        //column1.setText(c.getString(3)); 
        column1.setText(Integer.toString(c.getPosition()));
        TR.addView(column1);                

        column2.setGravity(0x01);
        column2.setTextColor(0xff000000);
        column2.setTextSize(2,20);
        column2.setText(c.getString(0));
        TR.addView(column2);        

        column3.setGravity(0x01);
        column3.setTextColor(0xff000000);
        column3.setTextSize(2,20);
        //column3.setText(c.getString(1));
        column3.setText(Integer.toString(TR.getId()));
        TR.addView(column3);


        TR.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        TL.addView(TR);  

        1Total += c.getDouble(1);
        2Total += c.getDouble(2);
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
```

If I view the database using DDMS, everything is displayed in the correct order (the order in which I insert into the table).  However, when I try to display the data in a tablelayout, for some reason it organizes the values based on the KEY_NAME value.  So if I insert data into the table like "B - C - D - A - E" it will populate my table layout with "A - B - C - D - E"

Something strange is that I have it setup so that a longclick on any given row with generate a dialogfragment displaying the rest of the information, and this information is correct.  So if using the example above I long click on the displayed "C" row then I will actually get the data for "D" which is correct.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the javadocs for the SQLiteDatabase class, for the query method, it says that "Passing null [for sort order] will use the default sort order, which ***may*** be unordered."  That null is one of the many nulls you are passing, and so the order ***may*** be unordered, but apparently it ***may*** be ordered instead.

Perhaps try using [`public Cursor rawQuery (String sql, String[] selectionArgs)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) instead of query?

So I think for your case that would be something like

`public Cursor rawQuery (String "SELECT DISTINCT KEY_NAME, KEY_1,KEY_2, KEY_3,
                KEY_4, KEY_5, KEY6, KEY_7, KEY_8, KEY_9, KEY_10, KEY_11, KEY_12,
                KEY_13 FROM DATABASE TABLE", null);`

It's been my experience that Android SQLite returns rawQuery results in the insert order, although I'm not sure that it's required to.  A more solid way to do it would be to add autoincrement key column -- giving each row a serial number, essentially -- and then ordering the results of queries on that.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer as the solution.  They way I solved it was essentially what you said in the second part.  I already had an autoincrementing id, but what I was not doing is returning the id in my query statement.  I also edited the query function call to  look like this:
  Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String []{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_1, KEY_2, KEY_3,KEY_4, 5, KEY_6,KEY_7, KEY_8, KEY_9, KEY_10, KEY_11, KEY_12, KEY_13}, null, null, null, null, KEY_ROWID);